# javascript find in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this:

```
  var movies = [
  { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998", Director: "François Girard" },
  { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999", Director: "Stanley Kubrick" },
  { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976", Director: "Mauro Bolognini" }
  ];
```

I want to find the location of the movie that's released in 1999.

Should return `1`.

What's the easiest way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to iterate through each value and check.

```
for(var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    if (movies[i].ReleaseYear === "1999") {
        // i is the index
    }
}
```

Since JavaScript has recently added support for most common [collection operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/new_in_javascript_1.6) and this is clearly a filter operation on a collection, instead you could also do:

```
var moviesReleasedIn1999 = movies.filter(function(movie) {
    return movie.ReleaseYear == "1999";
});
```

assuming you're not interested in the indexes but the actual data objects. Most people aren't anyways :)

`.filter` is not supported in all browsers, but you can add it yourself to your code base:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility

Comment: if you only need to get one movie then add a `break;` at the end, before closing the `if`. PS: Great avatar!

Comment: One quick note.  You will want to break out of that loop once the condition is satisfied.  Could do a "return i;"

Comment: Yes, or `return i;` if it is a function. (in addition to my previous comment)

Comment: Thanks @JCOC611 and @Aliester. I'm assuming OP wants to process each entry having the year 1999, otherwise adding a break is a good optimization. The avatar is from a facebook app, can't remember which :)

Comment: This approach will work if you only need the first occurrence of a movie in 1999.  You'd want to do it differently if there could be more than one movie that has 1999 for ReleaseYear.

Comment: Maybe he could `.push()` each index into an array and return the array (if it's a function). PS: Oh, cool! It made me laugh like crazy!

Comment: Great answer. .filter is awesome

Answer (score 2):

Built in?  Use loops.

You want to get fancy?  Linq to Javascript: http://jslinq.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
function findMovieIndices(movies, prop, value) {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = movies.length; i--; ) {
        if(movies[i][prop] === value) {
            result.push(i); // personally I would return the movie objects
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var indices = findMovieIndices(movies, "ReleaseYear", "1999");
```

Maybe this gives you some idea for a more generalized function (if you need it).

Comment: +1, but diff usecases. for example jquery $.inArray returns the key too.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've also tagged it with jQuery, you could use the 'map' function:

```
var movies = $.map(movies,function(item,index){
    return item.ReleaseYear == 1999 ? index : null; 
});
```

This will return an array of indexes for all movies with the year of 1999. If you wanted the movies themselves as an array:

```
var movies = $.map(movies,function(item){
    return item.ReleaseYear == 1999 ? item : null; 
});
```

Comment: @Raynos - This is using the jQuery map function. If anything other than `null` or `undefined` is returned then it will insert that into the resulting array.

Comment: my original comment was wrong but the solution doesn't really handle a not found case apart from returning an empty array.

Comment: @Raynos An empty set is my way of handling not found :)

Answer (score 1):

If functional style programming is applicable:

`_.indexOf(_.pluck(movies, "ReleaseYear"), "1999")`

Because it's that simple. The functional toolkit that is `underscore.js` can be very powerful.

[`_.indexOf`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#indexOf) , [`._pluck`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own searching function.

```
Array.prototype.findMovieByYear = function (findYear) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        // this actually returns the element, maybe you just want
        // to return the array index ( the i param )
        if (this[i].Release == findYear) return this[i];
    }

    return null;
    // or return -1 or whatever if you want to return the index

};

// now you can call:
movies.findMovieByYear('1998');
// and that should return
{ Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998", Director: "François Girard" }
```

Of course, this way of doing it actually affects every array you create.. which is maybe not what you want.. you can create your own array object then ...

Comment: Don't extend native prototypes. We all know it's a bad idea because it ruins `for in` loops and breaks various 3rd party libraries. At least put a disclaimer on it.

Comment: @Raynos: Well, you should not use `for...in` for arrays anyway ;) But yes, I remember a problem with jQuery and extended `Object` or `Array` prototype...

Comment: @FelixKling it's not me that i'm worried about as much as fellow programmers and other 3rd party libraries / plugins.

Comment: Thanks guys, small mistake :) but I already mentioned that you should create your own object, instead of extending the array prototype.. for simplicity's sake I just wanted to keep the code simple (and I don't like typing code into the SO textbox)