# Making a subset of an array of JavaScript objects based on one of their properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JavaScript array of objects with the same properties each, something like this:

```
box[0] = { name: 'somename', /* more properties... */ };
box[1] = { name: 'othername', /* more properties... */ };
box[2] = { name: 'onemorename', /* more properties... */ };
// more objects in the array...
```

I want to subset this array so that it only contains objects that match a **"list"** of names and copy the ones that don't to another array named `cache` maybe. I was thinking maybe I could compare this array of objects to another array which just contains a list of strings with the desired names to match against, checking each object's name property against this list to create a new array with the ones that matched. I don't know if this would work or if it is the best approach to achieve what I want, that is why I am asking for your help. Maybe checking each of 200-500 objects against a list with 100 names is not a very good thing to do, I don't know really.

Do you have any ideas on how I could do this? even better, can you point me to an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this questions comes very close to what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893835/javascript-find-in-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the list of names you do want are stored in an array,

```
var wantedNames = [ "first name", "second name", .. ];
```

have two arrays - those matching a name and those that don't. Loop through each item in the box object, and if it contains a name from the list, then include it.

```
var objectsMatchingName = box.filter(function(item) {
    return wantedNames.indexOf(item.name) !== -1;
});

var cache = box.filter(function(item) {
    return objectsMatchingName.indexOf(item) === -1;
});
```

I wish there was a array difference operation of some kind, so you could do (in pseudocode):

```
var cache = box - objectsMatchingName
```

Comment: forEach is not standard. & indexOf is not standard

Comment: @Raynos It's ECMAScript 5 I believe... http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18 http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.14

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this right know with Underscore.js library so I can use forEach & indexOf, I'll let you know how it worked.

Comment: I think Underscore.js uses the native forEach & indexOf if available, if not it creates them so that will do I guess

Comment: @VerizonW It's implemented in every browser except IE8 and below http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: What do you think of this? `box = box.filter(function (item) { if (wantedNames.indexOf(item.name) === -1) { cache.push(item); return false; } else { return true; } });` maybe it is faster as it only walks the array once.

Comment: @VerizonW - that works just as well. I was just trying to keep the side-effects down :)